# Laravel ORM to json: specify which columns are shown

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Here are my models:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'movieID';

    public function titles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Title', 'movieID');
    }
}


class Title extends Model
{
    public function movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie');
    }
}
```

now in my controller I want to fetch all Movies with all its titles with a simple where clause vie ORM like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $today = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');

    $collection = Movie::with('titles')
        ->where('date', '>', $today)
        ->get(array('movieID', 'date as releaseDate'));

    return Response::json($collection);
}
```

this works fine, but now I get a json with only my selected columns from Movie, but the nested Title Objects are listed with ALL its attributes. How can I limit this to, lets say only the `title` and `language` attribute of Title?

I tried this:

```
public function index()
{
    $today = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');

    $collection = Movie::
        with(array('titles' => function ($query) {
            return $query->select('title', 'language', 'movieID')->get();
        }))
        ->where('date', '>', $today)
        ->get(array('movieID', 'date as releaseDate'));

    return Response::json($collection);
}
```

This way I get the desired output, but I have to select the movie_id in Title as well, otherwise the data can not be linked.

Do I have to 'reparse' my collection?

Comment: You are doing it right. The foreign key is needed by Laravel. If you don't want it you indeed have to manually remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't send raw sql results to json. Use transformers:

- Return only those fields that you need.
- Or try [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) package.

But if you don't want to load any extra package, you may look here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: thanks for your answer. Tried Fractal and it works like a charm.